# Can we get the list of the items like facebook give when we click watching from facebook app?

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api

Question might not describe what i want and sorry for that, so here is the describtion.

In facebook for our status, when we click watching  we get a list of item as shown in image, wanna get this list with relevant data(if possible).

[image]

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I dig into Facebook SDK and didn't find anything like this !

Comment: @Hima parmar are u sure abt?

Comment: Yes, as far as I researched.

Comment: pls let me know if anybody know something abt it

Answer (score 0):

This is the Opengraph action `video.wants_to_watch`. Have a look at the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/video.wants_to_watch/

With the iOS SDK, the sample code would be

```
// For more complex open graph stories, use `FBSDKShareAPI`
// with `FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent`
/* make the API call */
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                               initWithGraphPath:@"/me/video.wants_to_watch"
                               parameters:params
                               HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
                               [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                               id result,
                               NSError *error) {
                                  // Handle the result
                             }];
```

Comment: as it clearly stated it only give those item which user want to watch not all the item pls read the qustion carefully, i already try the above api, please have another look on it

Comment: The question's headline is *Can we get the list of the item which user going to watch in fbsdk* . And, in the text: *How can we get(if possible) the list of items which user going to watch*. So what exactly do you wan to tell me? Be more clear then!

Comment: **WHAT** is possible? First, you should state what you want... the screenshot does not fit to your question's headline and the text.

Comment: please read  "To be more clear when we click watching in facebook we get a list of item as shown in image, wanna get the list with relevant data." and then see the image

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question, Anurag wants to display check mark to already watched Facebook video.

Graph API already mentions that you can have list of **video.watches** and **video.wants_to_watch** from the [Open Graph Reference Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph).

Also see this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-actions#explicitsharing which mentions Use the **video.watches** action to show someone has watched a video with your app. May this help you and make you more clear ! 
[image]